# Find how many payements will I need to do and what is going to be the final amount.

Tags: problem-solving, finance

This is a financial mathematics problem:

On time $0$ we have to pay $297505.48$ of a loan. Assuming a capitalization interest of $8\%$ and a fixed annual payment of $49623.55$, how many payments will yet be necessary, and what will be the amount of the last payment?

I could find the answer guessing, but as a newbie in financial mathematics I'd like to understand how to face such kind of problem in a methodical way. To find a solution I think I might first approximate $n$ in

$$49623.55\frac{1.08^n-1}{0.08} = 297505.48(1.08)^n$$

then truncate $n$ to its integer and proceed with

$$297505.48(1.08)^n - 49623.55\frac{1.08^n-1}{0.08} = x$$

so I could finally say "I have to do $n$ more payments of $49623.55$ and a final payment of $x$". My first problem is I don't know how to solve the first equation, and the second one is that I have the feeling I might be facing the problem in an impractical way. How should I solve this exercice?

Comment: Do you make the payments at the beginning or at the end of the years?

Comment: Assuming you make the payments at the end of the years, then you have to multiply the LHS by 1.08 of your last equation to obtain the value of the 9th and last payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, divide through by $1.08^n$ to get $$49623.55\frac{1-1.08^{-n}}{0.08} = 297505.48$$  Then a little manipulation gives $$1.08^{-n}=1-.08{297505.48\over49623.55}\approx0.52038017$$ and $$
n \approx -{\log{.52038017}\over \log{1.08}}=8.487354494309074$$

Truncating to an integer, we would take $n=8.$  Your method of computing the residual payment looks correct to me.